# how to add a specific number of items as long as the condition is true JavaScript Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on column selection from a table. I have a limit of 20 elements. I need to be able to select all items until the limit is passed.

Scenario:
18/20

- next column has 10 elements
- click on select whole column
- it should select only the first two elements

What I've tried:

```
const myArray = selectedColumn.some(() => itemsOnArray.length <= 20)
  ? selectedLaborer.map((laborer) => laborer)
  : [];
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more context to your question?

Personally when it comes to selections, i usually gives an id to the object i wish to select if they don't have one (An unique identifier) and store this value in an array as my selected objects.

Adding and removing values is quite easy then :

(This is typescript for more explicit reading, but doesnt change anything)

```
let selectedItems: string[] = [];
const MAX_ALLOWER_SELECTED = 20;

const selectItem = (itemId: string): void => {
    //You might want to check for duplicates before inserting
    if (selectedItems.length > MAX_ALLOWED_SELECTED)
        return;
    selectedItems.push(itemId);
}

const unselectItem = (itemId: string): void => {
    selectedItems = selectedItems.filter(id => itemId !== id);
}

const isItemSelected = (itemId: string): boolean => {
    return selectedItems.includes(itemId);
}
```

Comment: hello, i think that you misunderstood the question. When i click on column select then it selects 10 items at once. From that items i need to select available amount of limit

Comment: Well you can simply check for array length before the select, i edited the answer :)

Comment: Can we automate this to filter it inside array?

Comment: What do you mean to filter it ?